# Loading rows from an odata service into windows phone 8 database

Tags: sql-server-ce, odata, windows-phone-8

I am writing a windows phone 8 app that will consume data from the northwind database from an odata source, add the data to a local sql server database (offline storage), make changes to the data and send them back up to the remote database when back online.

The bit im stuck on is the parsing of the odata data and writing it to the local database.

I can consume data using the following code:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh286405(v=vs.105).aspx

I can create a local database and make modifications to the rows using:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh286405(v=vs.105).aspx

But i cant for the life of me put the odata into the local database.  Any help greatfully recieved.

Answer (score 0):

with jaydata to fetch records from remote database using oData and persist them into local store takes just ~10 line: (dislamer: I work for JayData)

```
        function sync(remote, local) {
            var suppliers = remote.Suppliers.toArray();
            var categories = remote.Categories.toArray();
            var products = remote.Products.toArray();
            return $.when(suppliers, categories, products)
                    .then(function (suppliers, categories, products) {
                        local.addMany(suppliers);
                        local.addMany(categories);
                        local.addMany(products);
                        return local.saveChanges();
                    });
        }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, but for the moment while im learning, i would like to know the 'standard' way, even if i have to write more lines of code.  Are you able to help me with that?